# Unable to add admob ads on my app

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add admob ads on my app (This is the first time) 
My app was working fine till now until i added the ad now it crashes and does not open.
i made following changes after which the app is crashing.

In the main class :

```
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
             adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

In manifest :

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />




 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

In the xml :

```
     <com.google.ads.AdView

     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     ads:adUnitId="a15120ccc0ed0ee"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
 />
```

My app crashes as soon as i install and try to open on my device. I added the admob sdk by going in the prop-> external jars and now the jar is showing up in the referenced library 
sdk version for admob is 6.3.0

Comment: Post your crash stacktrace too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..

I directly took the external jar file from the hard disk location.

Then i tried to move it in the libs folder then adding the external jar of the adsdk in the program.

Now it works fine and no crash is occurring.